# MySQL not found on Mac, problems with eclipse project using mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have the following problem: 
I imported an existing project into eclipse. This project references the library `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar`. 
When I try to run the project I get the following errors:

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Warning, not in CLASSPATH?
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

So I tried to find out if mySQL is installed by using the terminal: type -a mysql command. Result: type: mysql: not found
Now I downloaded and installed mysql. It is listed in /usr/local/ now. But the command: type -a mysql still shows the same result and the java application produces the same errors. 
What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that mysql process is running...

```
$ ps ax | grep mysql
```

... and that mysql driver jar is really in your project class path (library).

Comment: mysql process is running. and there is a mysql driver jar in the class path. still the same error.